# Learning modern algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, advice

I have read several posts on road maps for learning modern algebraic geometry, but it seems that whenever I open up a book on the subject (Hartshorne or Vakil's notes or Qing Liu) I make no progress whatsoever or I hit some bunp early on where I cannot proceed. I feel like this shouldn't be the case as I should have the necessary background (courses I took):

Algebra (groups, rings, fields, Sylow Theorems, Isomorphism Theorems; basically a standard course right before Galois Theory)

Commutative algebra (based on Atiyah)

Topology (Munkres)

Intro to Algebraic Geometry (classical algebraic geometry over a fixed algebraically closed field; basically chapter 1 of Hartshorne)

The main issue that I have for instance with Vakil is that I end up going down a rabbit hole. Let's say he mentions something about categories, then I go and read his section or something in a category theory book and by the time I learned that several hours passed and I forgot why I ventured away. It feels like I have to keep so many definitions and concepts in my head to just progress 2-3 lines in Vakil's notes. Another instance is that I made it to the definition of an affine scheme and I had to look up again what precisely was the meaning of a ringed space. How should I tackle this issue of keeping breadth of data in my head? Also an issue with Vakil's notes is that a lot of his motivation and intuition he uses comes from manifolds which I know nothing about or that it's difficult to screen his text for information that is important.

With Hartshorne it's even tougher. Are there perhaps other references that might be better suited for me? Or should I just progress this slowly and always keep algebra, topology, category theory books at hand and look everything up as needed?

Comment: First of all, modern algebraic geometry is darn difficult, it may well be that you're mathematically not ready yet even if you theoretically already have the prerequisites. On the other hand, are you working through the exercises? It sounds like that you're reading some sections too quickly and haven't digested some notions well enough (at least this is a trap I often fall into). But getting into accord with all of the abstraction in the beginning is definitely hard, you will get used to it though. E.g. a ringed space is just a space with a sheaf of rings (as the name would suggest).

Comment: It might also help to read Vakil's section on category theory (or any other category theory book) a bit more carefully before going on, as it seems like this is one part you (rightfully) struggle with.

Comment: It's not too bad that you don't know differential geometry (though you should study it at some point), you can ignore the comments in the book. The basic idea to keep in mind is that a manifold consists of locally Euclidean patches, which is only its definition (read it up!) which motivates the notion of schemes. Of course, some ideas will be related, but you don't need to know differential geometry to digest the ideas in Vakil.

(Sorry for the many comments, I didn't expect to write this much, maybe I should turn those into a more carefully written answer...)

Comment: One mindset I find helpful to have is to think as to think, at least initially as your objective to be studying the (tangible), rigid geometry of projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. In this setting, we have so many tools, analysis, topology, commutative algebra, and we really want to use all of them. Then the scheme theoretic perspective/category theory is all about broadening our perspective (allowing more exotic geometric objects), and our toolbox of stuff we can use to analyse them.

Comment: A meta point here is: Do you have people you can talk to? Anything from more senior students to professors? Often what gets lost in text books is intuition or motivation behind all the technical machinery

Comment: In Vakil's notes, and indeed in virtually every textbook, there are topics that can and should be skipped during a first reading. Even the authors themselves pick and choose which things they should cover while teaching a course from their books. Vakil taught an online version of his course with video lectures available [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy3u23mZE4TyW88yr6JLx9A). These lectures are a great supplement to the notes, and will also guide you on which sections to focus on.